# Eclipse remote application debug doesn't use specified login shell

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse CDT to debug my application. I've got it set to use SSH to connect to the local machine, but the setting for the login shell isn't working. Regardless of what I set the login shell to, it just uses bash and nothing else.

I'm using Eclipse CDT Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200

Here's the settings I have for the Run Configuration. Also see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaUSQ.png).

- Configuration type: C/C++ Remote Application
- Connection: Localhost (the one described below)
- Remote Absolute File Path: `/usr/local/bin/myApplication` (Eventually I'm going to add something to copy it here even when debugging. That's not important right now.)
- Commands to execute before application: `ps` (To see what shell is really running.)

Here's the settings I have for the connection named "Localhost". Also see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSulS.png).

- Host: 127.0.0.1
- User: the main user I'm logged in to the machine as
- Public key-based authentication, no password.
- Use login shell: Yes
- Login shell command: `/bin/csh` (I'm not actually interested in csh, it's just a test to verify that this setting has some effect.)

When I run, I get this output:

```
Last login: Fri May 11 19:22:36 2018 from localhost

ps;/usr/local/bin/myApplication;exit

[dyaw@localhost ~]$ ps;/usr/local/bin/myApplication;exit
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
35794 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
35844 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
-bash: /usr/local/bin/myApplication: No such file or directory
logout
```

So, as process 35794 says, it's definitely running `bash`, not `csh`, as the shell.

Is there some setting I need to set in order for this setting to take effect? Is there some global Eclipse setting, or perhaps something with my SSH config?

<sub><sub>Note: I'm tagging this as both eclipse and eclipse-cdt because I'm using CDT, but I believe the run dialog is the same as in regular Eclipse.</sub></sub>

Comment: Login shell depends on what shell is configured for the remote user. Eclipse configuration must be there to make remote command invocation compatible. In other words, login shell on remote is defined on remote.

Comment: if the login shell is only defined on the remote machine, what does this setting do in Eclipse? Does it do anything, ever? Since my remote machine is the local machine, is there some configuration option I can set to enable this Eclipse setting to take effect?

Comment: The Eclipse setting probably is there to define compatibility when sending the command, in other words to match syntax, capabilities, etc.